# Where did my shiny web app write the table to?

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shiny-server

I was trying to make up a shiny web app, for which I want to record each online data input and append them to an .csv file.

My current code for server.R is listed below. It can append to the csv file in my local bundle folder when I click "Run App" in RStudio. But after I upload them to https://brianzhang1994.shinyapps.io/Anqi/, I do not know where the shiny app wrote the table to. Even when I download the bundle file, the .csv file inside is exactly the same as when i uploaded.

How can I fix this question?

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
output$tableforpatient <- renderDataTable({
patientall <- read.table("brian.csv")
patient <- data.frame(firstname=input$firstname,
                      lastname=input$lastname,
                      dob=input$dob,
                      number=paste0("+1",input$numbers),
                      email=input$email,
                      joined=Sys.Date())
write.table(patient, file = "brian.csv", sep = ",", append = TRUE,
            row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
patient
                                         })
                                     })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `reactiveValues`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  my <- reactiveValues(patientall=read.table("brian.csv"))
  output$tableforpatient <- renderDataTable({my$patientall})
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    patient <- data.frame(firstname=input$firstname,
                          lastname=input$lastname,
                          dob=input$dob,
                          number=paste0("+1",input$numbers),
                          email=input$email,
                          joined=Sys.Date())
    my$patientall <- rbind(my$patientall,patient)
  })
})
```

Note usage of submit action button to avoid creating incomplete patients

Comment: How can I get the new dateset after rbind?

Comment: it will be rendered whenever it changes. its name is `my$patientall`